# Invoke like operations on ASP.NET Web Api DataController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

## Context

Coming from a RIA services background I've come to grow accustomed to the fact that I can add Insert, Update, Delete and Invoke operations to a domain service. Seeing the new DataController API in ASP.NET looking much the same I thought it would work there too.

Apparantly I'm wrong, because there is a InsertAttribute, UpdateAttribute and a DeleteAttribute, but no InvokeAttribute in the API for DataController.

## Question

Looking at the new Web API / DataController API does anyone have a good idea as to how I can add Invoke like functionality as was possible in RIA services?

Comment: I think ASP.Net Web Api is focused on making RESTful services easy to create and based on my understanding Invoke is not something you'd see in that scenario.

Comment: It still is something that happens in everyday REST services. I think it's a perfectly practical thing to do.